# Get Xaml and C# code from my app installed on my Windows 10 Phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10-mobile, visual-studio-2015

I've lost the solution file of my app but it's installed on my phone. How can i retrive the xaml and C# code to continue developing it?

Comment: The answer by user3621898 is correct, though you must expect the code to not be exactly the same as what you had depending on the compilation settings you had (ex: dead code removal). Are you able to extract the app from the phone to the computer or was that part of your question too?

Comment: I don't know windows phone that well, but you might not be able to recover the xaml if it was set to be compiled. It will depend on if the decompilers can do it or not (I've never tried).

Comment: No, I don't know how can I extract the app from the phone.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can, atleast not without reverse engineering the xap file.

A while ago it was possible to just rename the .xap file to .zip and open it, I dont know if this still works.

If you managed to get the dll's from the xap file then you can try using dotPeek to decompile them.

Comment: But, how can I extract the app from the phone?

Comment: I dont think there is a way to extract the installed app. But the installation file .XAP might still be somewhere on your phone. I'm not very familiar with windows phones, but you should try to do a full search with a file manager for .xap

Comment: @CristianCundari, maybe this will be able to help you: http://www.lemmymorgan.com/how-to-extract-your-xap-file-from-windows-phone-7-8-to-your-pc/ Article talks about backing up, but it might help you actually extract it. The extractor described in the article seems to already know how to navigate within a xap archive.